# Converting html to json with pandoc

Tags: html, json, pandoc, format-conversion

I'm trying to take html and generate some json that keeps the same structure.

I'm trying to use pandoc, as i've had some success in transforming things from format A to format B using pandoc before.

I'm trying to convert this file:

**example.html**

```
<p>Hello guys! What's up?</p>
```

Using the command:

```
pandoc -f html -t json example.html
```

What i expect is something like:

```
[{ "p": "Hello guys! What's up?"}]
```

What i get is:

```
[
  { "Para":
    [
      {"t": "Str", "c": "Hello"},
      {"t": "Space"},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "guys!"},
      {"t": "Space"},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "What's"},
      {"t": "Space"},
      {"t": "Str", "c": "up?"}
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem seems to be that when pandoc reads the text content, it separates every word based on the space character and makes an array out of it, while i expected pandoc to understand that the whole string is a single element.

I'm a beginner at pandoc and I've not been able to find out how to tweak that behavior.

Do you have an idea of how I can get the desired output? Do you know another tool that can do this? The tool, or the language it's written in doesn't matter.

Thanks.

**Edit**: You can test that behavior online on that [pandoc online tool](http://pandoc.org/try/?text=%3Cp%3EHello%20guys!%20What%27s%20up%3F%3C%2Fp%3E&from=html&to=json).

**Edit 2**: Workaround. I couldn't find how to do the HTML->JSON conversion with pandoc. As a workaround, i used the suggestion proposed in the comments, and implemented a solution using [Himalaya](https://www.npmjs.com/package/himalaya), which is a node package. The result is exactly what i wished for, even though it's not using pandoc.

Comment: Not to be smart, but why are you expecting such a result ? I don't see in the documentation the output formatting.

Comment: I know of one project that works closer to what you're expecting though : https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya

Demo : https://jew.ski/himalaya/

Comment: @Pogrindis Hi, I'm not trying to say that this behavior is inconsistent with the documentation. It is mostly that i expected it to behave differently. That's why i'm asking for help. Maybe there is an option to modify this behavior, but i don't know pandoc. So i was hoping someone here would know. Thanks for the link to himalaya, i'm gonna check it out.

Comment: @LoïcN. The JSON in the question is similar to the output produced by pandoc, but not identical. I assume that's because some manual transcription was involved. I recommend using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get human-readable JSON like so: `echo "<p>Hello guys! What's up?</p>" | pandoc -f html -t json | jq`.

Comment: @tarleb Hi tarleb. Thanks for the proposition. I tested your solution, but from what i can see, it restructured the result in a way that is easier to read, but the structure itself seems unchanged.

Comment: Right. My comment solely exists to point out how one could have inserted the actual JSON output in the question. See my edit.

Comment: @tarleb Yup, sorry about that. I misread your answer. Yes, you were right, i first used a written transcription which is why the output wasn't exactly the same as the actual output. Thanks for editing my original post with the correct value.

Comment: @PoGrindis I went with Himalaya, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the pandoc JSON representation is not very human-readable, but is auto-generated from the Haskell pandoc data types (aka document AST). There is some [discussion to change that eventually](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3211#issuecomment-258783108).

I guess you're looking for something like https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson? There also seem to be [plenty of commandline-tools that do that](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml+to+json+commandline).

Comment: Hi. I'm exactly look for something like codebeautify, but they don't specify the tools they use under their web interface. I've tried using the node module **xml-js**, but it produces errors when trying to read my html, while it works very well for other actual xml files that are more complex than what i tested. This is why i'm trying to get html->json rather than xml->json. Unless i can find a xml tool that is tolerant of html. As long as it works, that's all that matters. I'm testing **himalaya** at the moment, as recommended by Podgrindis.

Answer (score 3):

Pandoc, It's a tool to convert documents, the `json` representation of the document, It's just another representation that Pandoc can handle for the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)

```
Original Document --> Pandoc's AST --> Output Document
                   |                |
                pandoc           pandoc
```

Asking pandoc, to output a `json`, is to ask for the AST tree in it's `json` format,

If I understand correctly you would need something more like a `xml` to `json` converter like this [Python xmljson](https://pypi.org/project/xmljson/) module or an online tool like [this one](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/).

There are plenty of tools for that job as you picture it, just google XML to JSON convert.

The `json` representation of the AST used in pandoc, it normally used to output it from pandoc, and pipe it into another program that can handle `json` files, so you can alter the AST and make filters to manipulate the structure of your document.